# image from Database to a link in a tweet card (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter

I am trying to insert an image from database to twitter card (link) but the links appearing in the tweet without an image

example of the tweet card (link)

[image]

tried to make a default image for the tweet card and it work perfectly

but when i try to retrieve the name of the image from the database and put it in the `<meta>` it shows up as an empty image in twitter

tried also echoing `$picture` and the path shows up as its in the database : /image.png

```
<head>
<?php

            //identify the user
    $un = $_SESSION['active_user'];

        //query to get that specific users information
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un'";

        //save the query in result variable
        $result = $db->prepare($query);

        //excecute the variable result
        $result->execute();

        //if the result has records in the database save the users info in the variables below
    if ($row = $result->fetch())
        {
            //validation variables
            $emptyFields = false;
            $error = false;
            $success = false;

            $n = $row['name'];
            $usn = $row['username'];
            $picture=$row['picture'];

        }

echo "<meta property='twitter:card' content='summary'>";
echo "<meta property='twitter:site' content=''>";
echo "<meta property='twitter:title' content=''>";
echo "<meta property='twitter:description' content=''>";
echo "<meta property='twitter:image' content='https://website.com/".$picture."'>";
echo "<meta name='twitter:creator' content='@abc'>";
echo "<meta name='twitter:text:title' content='website'>";

?>
```

what am i missing here ? is the way i am retrieving data ? please i would try any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

i do not know how you saved the image to the location or to the database, but based on your question, 
**Read this and see if you missed something**
`twitter:image` is a url to a unique image representing the content of the page. You should **not** use a generic image such as your website logo, author photo, or other image that spans multiple pages. Images for this Card support an aspect ratio of 1:1 with minimum dimensions of 144x144 or maximum of 4096x4096 pixels. **Images must be less** than `5MB` in size. The image will be cropped to a square on all platforms. JPG, PNG, WEBP and GIF formats are supported. Only the first frame of an animated GIF will be used. SVG is not supported.
and also one more thing, it seems like you saved the entire or part of the image directory on the database, based on `database : /image.png` in your question. Note that this is not good practice since you might have to access the image from different pages of your website, and even though its not impossible, it's not worth it, just sve the image name only like `image.png`